# Devise + Omniauth multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I have seen a few solutions here, but none has answered my problem. I used devise to generate two models, namely: User and Designer. And I need to use Omniauth to signup/signin for this two models separately. Currently this is what I have:

User.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
   user.provider = auth.provider
   user.uid = auth.uid
   user.user_name = auth.info.name
   user.email = auth.info.email
   user.password = "password"
   user.skip_confirmation!
 end
```

user_authentications_controller.rb

```
class UserAuthenticationsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

 def create
    begin
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        sign_in_and_redirect @user
        #redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
        flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.first_name}!"
        UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver_now
      rescue
        flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
      end
  end
 end
```

designer.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |designer|
   designer.provider = auth.provider
   designer.uid = auth.uid
   designer.user_name = auth.info.name
   designer.email = auth.info.email
   designer.password = "password"
   designer.skip_confirmation!
  end
 end
```

designer_authentication_controller.rb

```
DesignerAuthenticationsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


  def create
    begin
        @designer = Designer.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        sign_in_and_redirect @designer
        #redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
        flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@designer.first_name}!"
        UserMailer.welcome(@designer).deliver_now
      rescue
        flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
      end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "user_authentications#create" end
devise_scope :designer do get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "designer_authentications#create" end
```

My problems are:

1) No matter from which page I signup, designer or user, It will sign up as User. I understand that is because it is using user_authentications_controller for both signup. Any ideas how can I let them determine which controller it will call by the signup page?

2) Am I doing the right way, or are there any better ways for multiple models signup?

Thanks. And please help!

Answer (score 2):

Let me share my experience here , i had done the same thing as you are currently doing . The issue might be you haven't followed all the steps throughout for both the users .

Here's a summary of steps to follow -

```
1) rails generate devise MODEL (user and designer)

2) rails generate devise:controllers [scope] (users and designers)

3) rails generate devise:views USER (users and deigners)
```

After this , do a rake routes and see how different routes are created by devise for both user and designer and call it accordingly .

To the best of my knowledge , it's better to use roles than to create different users as the codebase gets very messy later . If you are just starting to build one , roles are the way to go ahead .

Answer (score 0):

Why the need for two models? You could use the same auth and then make the distinction between user or designer through a role. I would take a look at some railscasts videos to get up to speed with the different techniques out there.

Roles with cancan:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Watch this one to get a sense on how to write your own Auth:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised